# single command to intersect redis sorted set by ranges

Tags: redis, jedis

redis:

```
redis>zadd zsetA 1 'A'
redis>zadd zsetA 2 'B'
redis>zadd zsetA 3 'C'
redis>zadd zsetA 5 'E'
redis>zadd zsetB 1 'A'
redis>zadd zsetB 2 'B'
redis>zadd zsetB 3 'C'
redis>zadd zsetB 4 'D'
```

opearate:

```
a=redis.ZRANGEBYSCORE 'zsetA',1,3
b=redis.ZRANGEBYSCORE 'zsetB',2,4
result=a∩b
```

how to quick get 'result' in sigle command?

Comment: do you want intersection or union of a and b ? (check the title and the meta code you wrote)

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli sorry.'intersection'

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: Woops! back in the day when I answered this question, I missed the point of the question and this answer is not what the original question is asking.*

I think what you are looking for is `ZINTERSTORE` (http://redis.io/commands/zinterstore).

Using your example above, it would be something like:

> `redis.ZINTERSTORE result, 2, 'zsetA', 'zsetB'`

And the result would be accesible by running `redis.ZRANGE result, 0, -1`

Comment: I think that's unlikely to produce the output specified by the requester. They're interested in the intersection of the output of two RANGE BY SCORE "slices", not the global intersection.

Comment: I agree, I made a mistake back then. What would you do with this answer? Remove it?

Comment: I'd go ahead and update it, or just mark it as "whoops" (as we already have)